# how to append and remove the values for the goods we select in ecommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my HTML CODE parsed from php server:

```
echo '<label class="product-label"><input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['categorie_id'].'" class="productcheck"/> '.$row['categorie'].'</label>';
```

This is my jquery ajax code that will be sent to the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.productcheck').click(function() { 
    var val1 = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'product_ajax.php',
       data: { choose: val1},
       beforeSend: function(load){  
          var html = "<img src='images/loading.gif' />";       
          $('#result').append(html);
       },
       success: function(response) {
          $('#result').html(response);
          $('.yearshow').hide();
       }
   });
});
```

This is the code that is being sent to the server side php file:

```
echo $_POST['choose'];
```

What i am trying to achieve is that whenever a user click on the category the response should be appended in the html code without loosing the previous value

at the same time if the user clicks again on the check box that is already checked then that value should be removed from the html side.

This is where the result is being appended:

```
<div class="col-sm-8" id="result"></div>
```

Any helps appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my english, i think you want to do like this ↓

```js
$(".productcheck").click(function() {
   var val1 =  $(this).val();

   if($(this).prop("checked")) {
     var result_msg = "<span data-value=" + val1 + ">" + "your response code here" + "<br></span>";
     $('#result').append(result_msg);
   } else {
     $('#result').find('[data-value="'+ val1 +'"]').remove();
   }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="product-label">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="productcheck"/>category-1</label>

<label class="product-label">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="productcheck"/>category-2</label>
<div class="col-sm-8" id="result"></div>
```

if it is you want to do, add to your ajax success functuon is good .

like this

```
$('.productcheck').click(function() {
var val1 = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'product_ajax.php',
    data: { choose: val1 },
    beforeSend: function(load) {
        var html = "<img src='images/loading.gif' />";
        $('#result').append(html);
    },

    success: function(response) {
            //add start
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            var result_msg = "<span data-value=" + val1 + ">" + "your response code here" + "</span>";
            $('#result').append(result_msg);
        } else {
            $('#result').find('[data-value="' + val1 + '"]').remove();
        };
        //add end
        $('.yearshow').hide();
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Might be it Help You.. Please Try with Your Code....
if Your checkbox is Not checked then You not need to call the Ajax...

```js
$('.productcheck').change(function() {
  var val1 = $(this).val();
if($(this).prop('checked'))
{
  //work when Checkbox is Checked
  //you can also put your ajax here
  $("div#result").append("<label id='" + val1 + "'> " + val1 + " </label>");
}else
{
// it work when Checkbox is Unchecked
  $("div#result").find("#"+val1).remove();
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="product-label"><input type="checkbox" value="pen" class="productcheck"/>Pen</label>
<label class="product-label"><input type="checkbox" value="Pencil" class="productcheck"/>Pencil</label>
<label class="product-label"><input type="checkbox" value="Book" class="productcheck"/>Book</label>

<div class="" id="result"></div>
```